# Counting the number of occurrences and compare to another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm working with 4D list counting the numbers of occurrences and then compare to a 3D list that I use for reference , I was able to do it, but I'm having problem during the comparison, this is my code:

```
from collections import Counter

reference = [[[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 2], [4, 2]], 
             [[2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 3]], 
             [[2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 3]]]

#This is my 4D list
coord = [[[[4, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 3], [4, 3]], [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]], [[[4, 2], [2, 3]], [[4, 3], [4, 3]], [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]]]

#To count the numbers of occurrences
occurrences = [[Counter(tuple(j) for j in i) for i in k] for k in coord]

print(occurrences)

ocurrences = [[Counter({(4, 2): 1, (2, 3): 1}), Counter({(4, 3): 2}), Counter({(3, 2): 1, (2, 3): 1, (3, 4): 1})], [Counter({(4, 2): 1, (2, 3): 1}), Counter({(4, 3): 2}), Counter({(3, 2): 1, (2, 3): 1, (3, 4): 1})]]
```

So far so good, It creates a list of list of `Counter` out of the 4D list, the first 3 `Counter` correspond to the first 3D list in the 4D list, and the next 3 `Counter` for the other 3D list. Now I need to compare the first list of `occurrences` with the `reference` list and then the second list of `occurrences` with the same references list. This is what I did:

```
out = [[[k[tuple(j)] for j in i] for k in cntr] for i,cntr in zip(reference,occurrences)]

print(out)

out = [[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]], [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1, 0]]]
```

For example the first `Counter` is `(4, 2): 1, (2, 3):1` if I compare the matching keys to the first list of `reference` ie `[[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 2], [4, 2]]`  I should get `[1, 0, 0, 1]` which is indeed what I get, but the second `Counter` is `(4, 3): 2`  and if I compare two the second list of reference I should get `[0, 0, 0, 2]` but I'm getting `[0, 0, 0, 0]` which is wrong. This is my desired output:

```
output = [[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1, 0]], [[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1, 0]]]
```

This is just an example just to simplify, I think it has to do something with the loop, but I'm not sure what is the problem, so any idea would be great, thank you!

Comment: This is just a small note but ```out = [[[k[tuple(j)] for j in i] for k in cntr] for i,cntr in zip(reference,occurrences)]``` is difficult to read and would probably be clearer in an explicit for loop (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate through each of the list of Counters in `ocurrences` and then get the frequency of each element in `reference` (as a tuple) from the corresponding counter

```
>>> [[[occ[i][tuple(r)] for r in ref] for i,ref in enumerate(reference)] for occ in ocurrences]
[[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1, 0]], [[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1, 0]]]
```